# Error returning html response instead of error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, error-handling

I've setup a custom error.html page and when a user tries to upload a large file it throws an error due to max request length (expected behaviour).

However, instead of returning a rendered page it returns the html of the error page and the network shows a 200 response instead of 500.

Here is what I have in the web config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/error.html">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.html" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/error.html" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

and under the webServer section

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="error.html" responseMode="File" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="error.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

It could be that these sections maybe conflicting with each other.

The expected error page is displayed for a 404.

(Increasing the limit is possible but won't stop the issue happening from a different error)

Comment: Try commenting httpErrors and checking again. This would help in checking if there is any conflict

Comment: Good idea - Just tried however it didn't work